# Facebook, pinterest post search based on hash tag not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am not able to fetch posts from facebook based on hashtags
Api i am using with valid  access token is :

> https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23shopping&limit=10000%20&access_token=xxxxxxxxxx

By access this URL i am getting an error code 11 and message "Post search has been deprecated"

Answer (score 1):

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_graph_api

under **Removed endpoints**:

> Public post search is no longer available. (`/search?type=post&q=foobar`)